# How to mute or change the screenshot sound?

Tags: audio, screenshots, alcatel

TCT (also called TCL) Alcatel 3T 10 (model 8088Q) Android 9 tablet makes a loud unpleasant sound when taking screenshots. On top of that, turning the DND or silent mode on doesn't mute the screenshot sound at all. Moreover, there are no settings available to change the sound of the screenshot or simply turn off or mute the screenshot sound. I contacted the brand, but they provided zero support.

Just FYI, after a long time, I have been able to find the app [Mute Mode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mggm.shiiitmode) in Google Play Store. This app has capability to mute all sounds of the tablet. It can also mute sounds of selected apps which is very helpful. So this app can successfully mute this unpleasant screenshot sound but only if I mute everything. There is no option to mute just the screenshot sound. So that's one drawback of this app. There is risk factor as well with this app. Suppose if I forget to turn off this app, then it will mute all alarms and notifications which is risky and impractical for daily stress-free usage.

How to mute or change the screenshot sound?